# React Ant Tooltip onHover Select values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have Select component with values, i need realizate logic when user choose more than one value, it will be appear comma separated in the select component and on hover view full list in tooltip. Fot it using `@ant-desing`. I use `onMouseEnter` function in `Select` component props, this function called when mouse enter.But, on hover, the function does not return the tooltip component

[Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q22znz?file=src/App.js)

```
  const tooltipValue = ["Mercedes", "BMW", 'Audi'].join(", ");
  const value = ["Mercedes", "BMW", 'Audi'];

  const renderToolTip = () => {
    console.log("success"); 

    return <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={tooltipValue} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={tooltipValue}>
        <Button>Tooltip</Button>
      </Tooltip>

      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        value={value}
        style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        onMouseEnter={renderToolTip}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i fully understand what you meant but maybe something like this?

try using the maxTagCount and the maxTagPlaceholder

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wlvn1u?file=src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Tooltip, Button, Select } from "antd";

export default function App() {

  const tooltipValue = ["Mercedes", "BMW", 'Audi'].join(", ");
  const value = ["Mercedes", "BMW", 'Audi'];

  const renderToolTip = () => {
    console.log("success"); 

    return <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={tooltipValue} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={tooltipValue}>
        <Button>Tooltip</Button>
      </Tooltip>

      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        value={value}
        style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        onMouseEnter={renderToolTip}
        maxTagCount={0}
        maxTagPlaceholder={<Tooltip title={value.map(v=><div>{v}</div>)}>{tooltipValue}</Tooltip>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, i added little changes, updated my sandbox link, please check if you interesting

Comment: the link you provided is to not working code

Comment: the code in the link produces error in sandbox (still)